# check whether the entered date is 18 years with days in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

i need to cheeck entered date is greater than 18 yrs or not
am using the following code

```
today = new Date();
          birthday_val = moment(self.$el.find(".Custdb").val(), "D-MMM-YYYY").toDate();
          birthday_val_months = birthday_val.getMonth();
          birthday_val_days = birthday_val.getDay();
          age = today.getFullYear() - birthday_val.getFullYear();
          if (today.getMonth() < birthday_val_months || (today.getMonth() === birthday_val_months && today.getDay() < birthday_val_days)) {
            age--;
          }

if(age<=18)   
{Age should be greater that 18 years}
```

If I select Jan 1st 1998 its showing msg age should be greater than 18 yrs

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: What is wrong with this code ?

Comment: if i select 1 st ,2 nd ,3rd of jan 1998 am getting error condition age should be 18

Answer (score 0):

This slightly modified version of your code should do the trick:

```
today = new Date();
birthday_val = moment(self.$el.find(".Custdb").val(), "D-MMM-YYYY").toDate();
age = today.getFullYear() - birthday_val.getFullYear();
month = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
if (month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < birthday_val.getDate()))   {
    age--;
}    

if(age<=18)   
{
   alert('You should be over 18 to use this site')
}
```